# The mean infective period in a SIR Model

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I'm going to quote the relevant passage in the textbook and then ask my question.

> > The assumption that the infectives leave the infective class at rate $\alpha I$ per unit time requires a fuller mathematical explanation,
> >     since the assumption of a recovery rate proprotional to the number of
> >     infectives has no clear epidemiological meaning. We consider the
> >     "cohort" of members who were all infected at one time and let $u(s)$
> >     denote the number of those who are still infective $s$ time units
> >     after having been infected. If a fraction $\alpha$ of these leave the
> >     infective class in unit time, then
>
> $$ u'=-\alpha u$$
>
> and the solution of this elementary differential equation is
>
> $$u(s)=u(0)e^{-\alpha s} .$$
>
> Thus, the fraction of infectives remaining infective $s$ units are
>   having become infective is $e^{-\alpha s}$, so that the lenth of the
>   infective period is distributed exponentially with mean 
>   $${\color{red}{\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{- \alpha s} \ ds = \frac{1}{\alpha}}}.$$

Now if the fraction of infectives remaining infective s units are having become infective is $e^{-\alpha s}$, then the fraction no longer infective $s$ units after having become infective is $1-e^{-\alpha s}$ which is the **cdf** of an exponential distribution.

Then since the pdf of an exponential distribution is $\alpha e^{- \alpha s}$, isn't then the mean infective period $$E(S) = \alpha \int_{0}^{\infty} se^{-\alpha s} \ ds = \frac{1}{\alpha} \ ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a non-negative random variable with density function $f(x)$ and cumulative distribution function $F(x)$, one way to calculate the mean is $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty x f(x) \; dx$ but another is $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) \; dx$.

You used the former while the book used the latter to get to the same result.

Note that you could write $E[X]= \displaystyle \int_0^\infty S(x) \; dx$ where $S(x)=1-F(x)$ is the survival function.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about that. To prove that don't you just need to express $\int_{0}^{\infty} (1-F(x)) \ dx$ as an iterated integral and then switch the order of integration?

Comment: You could use [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) to prove it. $$\int u(x) v'(x) \, dx = u(x) v(x) - \int u'(x) v(x) \, dx $$

Comment: If you integrate by parts, why is $ \displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} x \Big(1-F(x)\Big)$ necessarily zero?

Comment: @Did: If $x \Big(1-F(x)\Big)$ does not have a limit of $0$ when $x \to \infty$ then there is a $\delta \gt 0$ where we can find an infinite sequence $x_1, x_2,x_3 \ldots$ where $x_i \Big(1-F(x_i)\Big) \gt \delta$ and $x_{i+1} \gt 2 x_i$.  Chose the first $n$ of the sequence.

Comment: @Did: Then the mean $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty xf(x)\,dx$ $\displaystyle \ge \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \int_{x_j}^{x_{j+1}}xf(x)\,dx +  \int_{x_n}^{\infty}xf(x)\,dx$  $\displaystyle \ge \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} x_j\Big(F(x_{j+1})-F(x_j)\Big) +  x_nF(x_n)$ $\displaystyle \ge x_1 \Big(1-F(x_1)\Big) +\sum_{i=2}^{n} (x_{i}-x_{i-1}) \Big(1-F(x_i)\Big) $ $\displaystyle\ge x_1 \Big(1-F(x_1)\Big) +\sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac12 x_{i} \Big(1-F(x_i)\Big) $ $\displaystyle\ge n \frac\delta2$.   But since $n$ can be arbitrarily large this means that the mean would be infinite.

Comment: @Did: Thus, if the mean is finite then $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} x \Big(1-F(x)\Big)  =0$.

Comment: Simpler (and not assuming the existence of a PDF): $x(1-F(x))=E(X_x)$ where $X_x=x\mathbf 1_{X>x}$ hence $X_x\leqslant X$ for every $x$ and $X_x\to0$ almost surely. By Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, if $X$ is integrable, $E(X_x)\to0$, qed.